# how to decompress table and add more same values according to column?

Tags: mysql, window

How to make more rows from the table?  How to decompress table in MySQL?

```
+-----+-----------+
| num | frequency |
+-----+-----------+
| 0   | 3         |
| 1   | 1         |
| 2   | 2         |
| 3   | 1         |
+-----+-----------+
```

so that it looks like:

```
+-----+-----------+
| num | frequency |
+-----+-----------+
| 0   | 3         |
| 0   | 3         |
| 0   | 3         |
| 1   | 1         |
| 2   | 2         |
| 2   | 2         |
| 3   | 1         |
+-----+-----------+
```

I tried:

```
SELECT num,    
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num ORDER BY frequency) AS x
FROM numbers
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use aa join approach:

```sql
INSERT INTO yourTable (num, frequency)
SELECT t1.num, t1.frequency
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 AS frequency UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) t2
   ON t2.frequency < t1.frequency;
```

You may add more frequency vales to the `t2` subquery above as needed.